# How do i have python3 search for a specific string in a text file

Tags: linux, string, python-3.x, parsing, if-statement

All I'm trying to do is have the program look for a specific string and if the file contains that string add to a variable and if not just print that it didn't work. But it keeps saying that the string was not found when i know it is in the file.

```
for line in open("/home/cp/Desktop/config"):
    if "PermitRootLogin no" in line:
        num_of_points1 = num_of_points1 + 4
        num_of_vulns1 = num_of_vulns1 + 1
    else:
        print('sshd_config is still vulnerable')
        break
```

This is the file its reading off of

```
This should work
Possibly
PermitRootLogin no
hmmmmmmmmmm
aaa
```

What i want it to do is find that "PermitRootLogin no" in the file but it just keeps acting like that string was never found. And printing the else statement. When i was looking for tutorials they all were trying to do something else so i'm open to any suggestions. Thank You in advanced im just really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your problem is the break after your else.
Your code reads the first line and prints that the first line is not your searched string. 
The code below works for me.
Hope this helps.

```
found = False

for line in open('config'):
    if "PermitRootLogin no" in line:
        num_of_points1 = num_of_points1 + 4
        num_of_vulns1 = num_of_vulns1 + 1
        found = True
if not found:
    print('sshd_config is still vulnerable')
```

Comment: okay thank you so much, so it would only search the first line if i have the break stamen t?

Comment: @lavarockman The break command breaks the loop. If your else statement would fire in the e.g. third row then only three lines would be searched.